# native function for "vertical" sum of array sub elements like vertical_sum($array[$day_of_year]["income"]);

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

The headline says it all: Is there a vertical sum function in php that adds a (sub)array value over the entire array, like this:

```
 // pseudo code that would return the sum of "income" for all days of the year
 // for example
 vertical_sum($array[$day_of_year]["income"]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native function? Not exactly, but array reduction can help:

```
$array = array(
    array('income' => 1), //day 1
    array('income' => 3), //day 2, etc
    array('income' => 6),
    array('income' => 7)
);
echo array_reduce($array, function($curr_total, $this_val) {
    return $curr_total + $this_val['income'];
}, 0); //17
```

Comment: That's not quite what his array looks like.  Your example could just be `array_sum($array['sub_arr'])`.  His array is like `$arr = array(array('sub_arr' => 1),array('sub_arr' => 3),array('sub_arr' => 6),array('sub_arr' => 7))`.

Answer (score 3):

You could extract the `income` field from each array, and then use `array_sum`.

```
function vertical_sum($array, $key){
    return array_sum(array_map(function($a) use($key){
        return $a[$key];
    }, $array));
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
vertical_sum($array, "income");
```